# Validator not workind in Adonis

Tags: node.js, validation, adonis.js

I'm setting some validations in my code, and I want to use Validator from Adonis framework. I followed all steps in official documentatio, but nothing worked.

I triend to follow official documentation.
Installed Validator via CLI
Create my validator class using adonis make:validator User
Setted my rules
Attached validator in my routes

Here is my route:

```
Route.resource('users', 'UserController')
  .apiOnly() 
  .middleware('auth')
  .validator(new Map(
    [['users.store'], ['User']
  ]
  ))
```

I expecte something like some messages, but just return knex erros.

edit: yes, I registered validator in my provides.

Comment: Can you give more information as to what went wrong? Add a screenshot of the errors

Answer (score 3):

While using validators it is always good to create a validator class and write the rules and messages for those rules, then just attach that validator class to your routes. As adonis.js uses the Indicative library to do validation I would suggest you visit https://indicative.adonisjs.com/guides/master/introduction and check out how to write rules and messages.

create a validator folder in your app or src folder make sure you have adonis validator installed

create a login.js

```
class Login {
  get rules () {
    return {
        email: 'required|email',
        password: 'required'
    }
  }

  get messages () {
    return {
      'email.required': 'You must provide a email address.',
      'email.email': 'You must provide a valid email address.',
      'password.required': 'You must provide password.'
    }
  }

  async fails (errorMessages) {

    this.ctx.session.flash({ 
        alert: {
            message: errorMessages[0].message,
            type: 'warning'
        }
    });
    this.ctx.response.redirect('back');
    return
  }
}
```

then in the routes apply the validator like this

```
 Route.post('/login', 'AuthController.login').validator(['login'])
```

this technique also reduces the boiler plate code. And you can write validators and apply to multiple routes or route groups.